# Redux Form Component -> Value toString() behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I've a wired problem with toString() behavior of a input value in a (react) redux form. I need a dropdown menu, which contains numbers as values. The json looks like this:

```
{
 id: 1
 [...]
}
```

My component looks like this:

```
export class DropdownField extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var { input, meta: { touched, error } } = this.props
    //The tries of changing input.value to string are placed here
    //e.g. input.value = "2"
    return (
      <div className="field">
        <select {...input}>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

The issue here is, that the input.value isn't a string, so input.value=2 isn't recognized as "2". I thought, I could just change the input.value to a string to solve this. It works well if I do

```
input.value = "2" //Works
```

But no matter what, if I use the original input.value I can't get it to work, so the following isn't working:

```
input.value = input.value.toString(); //Doesn't work
input.value = "" + input.value; //Doesn't work
input.value = getString(input.value) //Doesn't work
//Just for completition, this plain stupid method. It runs in case 2, but still doesn't work
var getString = (input) =>
{
  switch(input)
  {
    case 1:
    return "1";
    case 2:
    return "2";
    default:
    return "what"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a idea what's going on here? I really just need to set up the initial value of the dropdown box, everything else works. As soon as I change the selection via the UI the input.value changes to the corresponding string value and can be saved.